# Removing variable mutation from reactive stream processing

Tags: kotlin, rx-java, reactive-programming

The following works, but I think it can be better i.e. more idiomatic rx/functional/less mutable.

```
var total = 0
var published = 0

service
    .getThings()
    .doOnNext { total++ }
    .flatMap { shouldPublish(it) }  // Returns empty() or just(it)
    .doOnNext { published++ }
    .subscribe { publishToSqs(it) }

println("Published $publish out of $total")
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can't you move `total++` and `published++` into `subscribe`?

Answer (score 0):

I normally use *'.scan()'* operator upon a *'.merge()'* d stream of events. That way there is always a valid snapshot of the latest state.

More about it here - [Reactive Aggregate State Pipeline](https://medium.com/@maxim.volgin/reactive-aggregate-state-pipeline-5a690383e18e)